# Python logging - How to get value of logging message that has a custom formatter

Tags: python, logging

I have a logger that I've added a handler to with a custom formatter, but I'd like to access what the resulting message is after going through my custom formatter. So my code looks something like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

some_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
some_handler.setFormatter(some_formatter) # some_formatter specified elsewhere

logger.addHandler(some_handler)
```

Now when I do a `logger.warning('hello')`, I see the message in the format that I specified in `some_formatter` (so maybe something like `'my message is: hello'`). But I'd like to access that formatted message in the code. How can I get what the resulting formatted message was from my `logger.info('hello')` in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default logging level is [`WARNING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel), which is the reason why `logger.info('hello')` since `INFO` is less severe than `WARNING`. Just add the following somewhere:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

This will set the lowest logged severity level to `INFO`.

---

As for your question, you'll need another handler. You *can* define your own `Handler` or create another `StreamHandler` with the stream set to a `StringIO`:

```
import logging
from io import StringIO

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

stream = StringIO()

some_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
some_handler.setFormatter(some_formatter)

some_other_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
some_other_handler.setFormatter(some_formatter)

logger.addHandler(some_handler)
logger.addHandler(some_other_handler)

# You hadn't specified your desired result format, so... I'm going to assume you want a list and assume all logs are single lined, but you can change it accordingly

def get_stream():
    stream.seek(0)
    return stream.read().strip().split('\n')

logger.warning("opps")
logger.info("nevermind")

current_streamed = get_stream()
print(current_streamed)
```

Output:

```
format: opps
format: nevermind
['format: opps', 'format: nevermind']
```

The first two came from logging, the list from `current_streamed`.

Comment: Ok I didn’t include the part where I set the severity level. I’ve edited my question. But my question remains the same

Comment: @Andrew Okay, I edited with the answer to what I think was your question.